# Read MySQL binary(16) UUID with Java

Tags: java, mysql, uuid

This should be a very simple question, I'm just missing something basic here and I'm having 'one of those days...'
Cannot use Hibernate or other ORM. Using Java PreparedStatement.

MySQL stuff:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `articleID` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `publisherID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`articleID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

insert into article ( articleID, publisherID )
values ( (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''))), 1111  );
```

Java stuff

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( "select articleID, publisherID from article" );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while( rs.next())
{
  byte[] artIDArr = rs.getBytes( "articleID" );
  UUID artID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes( artIDArr );
}

rs.close();
ps.close();
```

Now, reading the UUIDs from the database...

```
    select hex(articleID) from article;

1C711C50E4773873AB1533401E2F420C
A1FCD341EE9311E297B700FFB00BB509
A95E06B6EEE611E297B700FFB00BB509
```

But dumping out what I read in the java code:

```
6c825dc9-c98f-37ab-b01b-416294811a84
de6337f9-f276-3e30-b9a3-8d9338a1977f
57ccb5af-1a66-329f-b069-69638e1af24f
```

Now, is this because I'm removing the dashes from the UUID before storing them as binary, and the rehydration is assuming they're there?

What is the correct method for reading a UUID stored as binary(16) in MySql to a Jav UUID object?

Edit: if I change the the preparedStatment query to "select hex(articleID) as articleID..." and read it as a string, it's of course what the DB contains, but UUID throws an exception because the string is missing the dashes...

Comment: Are you sure it's worth it to store these as binary? The length savings is usually minimal, and it makes it super annoying to query manually.

Comment: Yup, we're going to have a brazillion records, and we need it to be a smaller PK. And yes, UUID isn't the best PK out there. I know. But it's what I've got. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UUID artID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(artIDArr);
```

Uses MD5 and patches bytes. Use something like

```
static UUID toUUID(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes.length != 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int i = 0;
    long msl = 0;
    for (; i < 8; i++) {
        msl = (msl << 8) | (bytes[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    long lsl = 0;
    for (; i < 16; i++) {
        lsl = (lsl << 8) | (bytes[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return new UUID(msl, lsl);
}
UUID artID = toUUID(artIDArr);
```

Comment: Java 7 jdk doesn't make the UUID( byte[] ) constructor visible..  "The constructor UUID(byte[]) is not visible"

Comment: @MonkeyWrench I did oversee that; made a function for it, and corrected answer.

Comment: lol. Maybe I should just store the dashes in the DB, use "hex()" in the select statement, and read them as a string in Java. But I'm surprised there isn't a better way to deal with this. "everyone" storing UUIDs in MySQL state using binary(16) is the way to go. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

So I solved this simply by wrapping the binary(16) with a hex() function call within the query. Not sure which is more efficient, having the DB handle the conversion or flipping the bits in Java. Either way, done.

```
  PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( "select hex(articleID) as articleID, publisherID from article" );

  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
  while( rs.next())
  {
    String artIDStr = rs.getString( "articleID" );
    UUID artID = getUUIDFromString( artIDStr );
```

I'll mark Eggen's answer as correct since he put in the effort and it probably works.  8)

Comment: It's a nice solution and fine if you are not constrained by performance concerns.  Parsing a 16 byte number into a String and then parsing the resulting String back into a 16 byte number (which is what a UUID is internally) is a solution which leaves the door open for performance improvements.