# Storing MySQL binary(16) with JayDeBeApi

Tags: python, mysql, jdbc, uuid, jaydebeapi

I need to store a UUID as `binary(16)` in MySQL using [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/), which uses JDBC under the hood. When I try to save the data using Python bytes, the data is not converted/or stored correctly.

When using one parameter

```py
curs.execute('INSERT INTO `user` (userId) VALUES (?)',
             (uuid.uuid4().bytes))
```

there is the following error:

> Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

When using two parameters

```py
curs.execute('INSERT INTO `user` (userId,username) VALUES (?, ?)',
             (uuid.uuid4().bytes, 'some_user'))
```

There's no error, but the data doesn't get stored correctly

```sh
mysql> select * from user;
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| userId                             | username  |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 | some_user |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
```

When I used `pymysql` it worked fine using `uuid.uuid4().bytes`. So what is the correct way to save the bytes (or just the UUID) using JayDeBeApi?

[Here is a reproducible example](https://github.com/psamsotha/stackoverflow-jaydebeapi-binarykey).

### UPDATE: (still open)

So I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69122481/2587435) using the `UNHEX()` function. Problem is that the `UNHEX()` function isn't portable. The reason I switched from `pymysql` to `jaydebeapi` is because I need to use H2 for testing. And H2 apparently doesn't have this same function. So if anyone has a different solution that doesn't involve using this function (or any at all), I would prefer that solution.

So for now, this question is still open.

Comment: `(uuid.uuid4().bytes), )` needs the comma to be a tuple might be the one parameter problem. The jdbc connection I've no idea.

Comment: @danblack I don't think that's the problem. With only one parameter, I can leave out the tuple and just pass the single value. When I do this, I get the same error message.

Comment: @danblack I think you were actually correct about this part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** Not a complete solution. I'm still looking for a way to do this without the use of a function as the function is not portable.

So with the help of [Inserting and selecting UUIDs as binary(16)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252188/2587435), I ended up using the `UNHEX` function to just un-hex the actual UUID string.

```py
curs.execute("INSERT INTO `user` (userId,username) VALUES (UNHEX(?), ?)",
             (user_id.hex, 'some_user'))
```

```sh
mysql> select * from user;
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| userId                             | username  |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| 0x7F69F93B0E9F48D0AE8C7D04C78B530F | some_user |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Also, it seems [dabblack was correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112165/storing-mysql-binary16-with-jaydebeapi#comment122151671_69112165) about the "one parameter" problem in regards to the tuple. When I try to use one parameter, if I don't add a comma, it's does work correctly. I'm not much of a Python user, so this is new to me.

```py
curs.execute("INSERT INTO `user` (userId) VALUES (UNHEX(?))",
            (user_id.hex,))
```

Comment: H2 does have [HEXTORAW](https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#hextoraw) which I assume is the same as `UNHEX`.

Comment: This is ultimately a nice workaround for JDBC not communicated the binary. [this blog](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JDBC/Binary/Insert_Binary_Data_into_a_Database_Table_Using_a_PreparedStatement_in_Java.htm) suggest that maybe fully use a prepared statement and use `pstmt.setBytes(1, binaryData)` to let jdbc handle it properly. I assume this is exposed too.

Comment: Option 3 - use [UUID](https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#random_uuid) so the server creates the uuid.

Comment: Thanks @danblack I'll look into it.

Comment: How did you go with these, or other, options?

Comment: @danblack So HEXTORAW didn't work out. It didn't actually convert the hex to bytes. What I did was find a library that added the UNHEX function to H2. So I just keep the UNHEX. Thanks for your help.